# Правильный поиск нод в React js

Tags: reactjs

Допустимо ли в react приложении (без redux) для поиска нод использовать document.getElementById вместо ReactDOM.findDOMNode()?
Например есть компонент, допустим кастомный селект, значение которого нужно получить из родительского. Ref в данном случае не доступен, могу ли я сделать

```
let val = document.getElementById('my-select').value;
```

При условии что не хочется делать компонент контролируемым

Answer (score 0):

Нет, так делать нельзя.
Вы опускаете callback из родителя в кастомный селект. Redux делает тоже самое, но менее явно. Или просто оставлять все свойства, выдергивая свой кастом.

```
const CustomSelect = ({ color, ...props }) => (
  <select className={`select-${color}`} {...props} />
);
```